# Set focus on input field with renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-renderer2

I have a button like below which opens a modal when I press "space"

```
<button type="button" (keydown.space)="openLg()" class="btn btn-link"></button>
```

and I want to set focus on a input field like below

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="amount" name="amount" [(ngModel)]="totalAmt_modal">
```

the openLg func is

```
openLg() { 
    
 this.renderer.selectRootElement('#amount').focus();

}
```

I have also import renderer2

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}
```

but when I am pressing the space button it is show me the following error

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: The selector "#amount" did not match any elements
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:679)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.js:267)
    at VoucherentryComponent.setfocus (voucherentry.component.ts:347)
    at VoucherentryComponent.openLg (voucherentry.component.ts:320)
    at VoucherentryComponent_tr_52_Template_button_keydown_space_2_listener (voucherentry.component.html:75)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15214)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15249)
    at platform-browser.js:582
    at platform-browser.js:1281
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
```

What is the solution? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hawgm4?file=src/app/app.component.ts. It is working fine for me. Could you please share a minimal reproducible code in stackblitz.com?

Comment: sorry for my late reply @smtaha512. The problem was in the modal. for some reason it was not focusing on modal input. I used ngbAutofocus. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the modal. for some reason it was not focusing on modal input. I used ngbAutofocus.